# Weblogic: defining a separate thread pool for a servlet

Tags: multithreading, performance, servlets, threadpool, weblogic-10.x

I have a Weblogic 10.3 server and an ear application deployed on it.

I want that one of the servlets (that this application uses) always will have free threads to perform requests. Can I set for this servlet a separate thread pool? Or can you advise me something else?

Thank you,
Alex

Comment: Why do you need this? WL usually manages the request threads without need for any thread pool adjustment. Have you experienced thread starvation for a particular Servlet?

Comment: I have a servlet A that calls several times the servlet B. I get a lot of requests for A from the client and in order to complete such request all the B requests need to be done. But there is not enough threads for B's because A requests from the client occupied all the threads.
So I want to allocate for B specific amount (or share) of threads.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out by myself.
I needed to define a workmanager in ***weblogic.xml*** of my application and in ***web.xml*** I needed to apply the new workmanager to my servlet.

More about creating and using workmanagers in WebLogic:
*http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13701/self_tuned.htm#CNFGD117
http://www.itbuzzpress.com/weblogic-tutorials/weblogic-pools-configuration/using-workmanagers-in-your-applications.html*